# Xcode Swift image zoom gesture

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage

Hope someone can help me. Im trying to make a zoom gesture, so when the image are presented the user can zoom the image with fingers.

My code to present the image are:

```
// MARK: Show image full screen

func imageTapped(img: AnyObject) {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

    let imageView = productImage as UIImageView

    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
    newImageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
    newImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissFullscreenImage:")
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use UIScrollView and add UIImgeView in scroll view**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    var scrollV : UIScrollView!
    var imageView : UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

        scrollV=UIScrollView()
        scrollV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        scrollV.minimumZoomScale=1
        scrollV.maximumZoomScale=3
        scrollV.bounces=false
        scrollV.delegate=self;
        self.view.addSubview(scrollV)

        imageView=UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "neymar.jpg")
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollV.frame.width, scrollV.frame.height)
        imageView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        scrollV.addSubview(imageView)
   }

   func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
   {
        return imageView
   }
}
```

Comment: How do i make the image show i full size when tapped ?

Comment: Add tap gesture on image view and create new view with image and cancel button. After clicked cancel button remove this view from superview

Answer (score 1):

Take gesture programmatically and make its method and write down this code in the method.

`pinchRecognizerOnView()` is my method name. Take one view or image view inside view controller and add this new view in that.Now apply gesture method on this new view.

```
func pinchRecognizerOnView(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!) {

    sender.view?.transform = CGAffineTransformScale((sender.view?.transform)!, sender.scale, sender.scale)

    sender.scale = 1

    // its for zoom in out screen
}
```